# Matlab code for finding cluster centre in hierarchial clustering

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to find the cluster centers in hierarchical clustering. Below is the code i use. But this returns only the cluster numbers for each of the observations.

```
c = clusterdata(input,'linkage','ward','savememory','off','maxclust',10);
```

I am dealing with multi-dimensional data (32 dimensions). Any ideas or code would be very helpful

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you define "center", but since you're going with hierarchical clustering, I'm assuming you don't have a parametric model for the distributions of your clusters. This simply computes the barycenter of all points in each cluster.

```
[n,p]  = size(input);
labels = clusterdata(input,'linkage','ward','savememory','off','maxclust',10);

centers = zeros(10,p);
for i = 1:10
    centers(i,:) = mean( input( labels == i, : ) );
end
```